# Setting an background image over an image set for a UIImageView - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am setting images to a `UIImage` programmatically.  But I want to also add a play button over that view.  Think of Facebook in how there is a play button over the image.  That is exactly what I am trying to figure out on what to do.  Here is my setting of the `UIImage`:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", indexPath.row]];
    cell.photoView.image = img;
```

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: you can do it like this, Create UIView and UIImageview on view ,set your image, now add play button on UIView

Comment: @surenderrathore do it like what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add playbutton either as a `UIButton` or a `UIImageView` and add as a subview to your `photoview`.

```
[cell.photoView addSubview:urPlayButtonView];
```